# k8s ingress redirect to endpoint outside the cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I am using google clould, GKE.

I have this example `ingress.yaml`:

```
  1 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  2 kind: Ingress
  3 metadata:
  4   name: kuard
  5   namespace: sample
  6   annotations:
  7     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  8     cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
  9     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://www.google.com
 10 spec:
 11   tls:
 12   - hosts:
 13     - example.gordion.io
 14     secretName: quickstart-example-tls
 15   rules:
 16   - host: example.gordion.io
 17     http:
 18       paths:
 19       - path: /
 20         backend:
 21           serviceName: kuard
 22           servicePort: 80
```

I need that when user request specific host, like: `example-2.gordion.io`, to be redirected to other site, outside the cluster, (on other google cluster actually), using nginx.

Currently I am aware only to the specific annonation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect` which seems to be global. How is it possible to redirct based on specific requested host in this ingress file?

Comment: is `example-2.gordion.io` site outside or inside the cluster?

Comment: Outside the cluster, other service on a cluster in different region, actually.  will edit the question to

Comment: meaning you can access `example-2.gordion.io` from both clusters but not from the outside world?

Comment: youre not replying so assuming im right i post my answer. feel free to comment on if you have any more questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you combine an externalName service with another ingress file:
In the following yaml file we define an [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname) service with the name `example-2.gordion.io-service`, which will lead to the real site service in the other cluster:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-2.gordion.io-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: internal-name-of-example-2.gordion.io
```

And an ingress file to direct `example-2.gordion.io` to `example-2.gordion.io-service`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example-2.gordion.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: example-2.gordion.io-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain why did you call it `internal-name-of-example-2.gordion.io`? I assume it's an external DNS name I am referencing to, right? the connection goes out to the public internet then returns to the other cluster?

Comment: if you have an external name for it than why do you need any ingress for it? i thought its internal

Comment: It is a service on another google cluster. I wanted to see if it's possible to manage the routing rules to this service with ingress in the main cluster . and as a bonus if it's possible to stay inside google network and not go outside (if the request have to go outside then maybe I can really create another ingress in the other cluster).  sorry if I confused you :)

Comment: got it. if want to restrict access only via the main ingress - you may find [vpc peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) useful. otherwise if you choose to keep the ingress at the other cluster, my advise for you is to keep your clusters separated as much as you can, thats considered a DR best practice. cheers!